# Arudino multiple leds on after one another

Tags: iot

I am new to Arduino and tindercad and I am unable to do this can anyone help me out. It would be a great help to me I have attached the question

Que:- Add a green and red LED to the circuit with the RGB LED. Include 2 buttons. The first button will toggle between the red and green LED. If the green LED is on when you hit button 2 the RGB will start cycling through the 3 colours. If the 2nd button is pressed the RGB lights stop. If the 1st button is pressed the RGB stops AND the green LED turn off and the red LED turns ON. If the red LED is on, nothing happens when you press the 2nd button.